# Nested sortable in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I had this jQueryUI sorting between nested `<ul>`-s working and I somehow broke something.

Problem: I can drag items in each list but cannot move items from one list to another. I swear this was working yesterday. One change I made: I had ALL the `<ul>`-s with `id="sortable"` but changed this to `class="sortable"` (because id is supposed to be unique). I also changed the selector in the JS from `#sortable` to `.sortable` to match. That wouldn't cause this, would it?

reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/DY2Ez/2/

```
/* JS */
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable({ items: "> li.s" });
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection(); 
        $( "li.cntrl" ).sortable({ disabled: true }); //make controls not sort
      });
```

Comment: If you were using `#sortable` before, your jQuery selector would only have matched one element. Now you're using `.sortable`, it's picking up all of them. That's a significant difference worth investigating.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/DY2Ez/3/

Comment: @JasonP That looks like it meets OP's requirements; worthwhile adding it as an answer surely?

Comment: @AdrianWragg His question isn't clear to me, and I don't like posting answers I'm not sure of.

Comment: Thanks @JasonP That does what i was after. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @gmdavisUX No need to be sorry. Turns out I did understand you after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JasonP provided an answer in the comment above. The third line of code should be:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({ items: "> li.s", connectWith:'.sortable' });
```

Added the connectWith option. I'm not sure why it worked previously without it.